# Is it possible to get one SSL certificate *.mysubdomain.example.com and mysubdomain.example.com

Tags: ssl, azure

Is it possible to get one SSL certificate `*.mysubdomain.example.com` and `mysubdomain.example.com`, I need because I am using 2 IP on my dedicated server but now I am moving to Azure on azure we can't add two https endpoint. or other solution for azure I need two https endpoint

Answer (score 3):

You can purchase a wildcard SSL certificate that encrypts requests made to *.example.com.  This will work for an unlimited number of third-level subdomains.  To include the second-level (example.com) and forth-level (subforthlev.subthirdlev.example.com) or higher subdomains, you must find a certificate authority (CA) that allows you to include multiple subject alternate names (SANs) in the wildcard certificate.   Each non third-level domain needs to be manually added as a SAN.

Edit: I've used [DigiCert's wildcard certificates](http://www.digicert.com/welcome/wildcard-plus.htm) several times and I have not come across a browser or device that did not have their root certificate installed (see their [compatibility list](http://www.digicert.com/welcome/compatibility.htm)).  DigiCert wildcard certs allow you to secure an unlimited number of subdomains regardless of the domain level.  Excerpt from first link:

> DigiCert WildCard ssl certificates are unique in allowing you to secure ANY subdomain of your domain, including multiple levels of subdomains with one certificate. For example, your WildCard for *.digicert.com com could include server1.sub.mail.digicert.com as a subject alternate name.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. Have you ever used this kind of certificate? does it have any browser implications? Please let me know if you have any links or documents on it.

Comment: I just updated my answer.  Out of curiosity, what certificate authority are you using?

Comment: Thanks again. i'm using GeoTrust certificate (http://www.geotrust.com). I'll check out digicert and see if it solves my issue.

Comment: This link (http://www.digicert.com/ssl-support/wildcard-san-names.htm) explains how to add additional SANs to a DigiCert wildcard cert.  You must use a SAN to register a fourth-level domain such as sub2.sub1.example.com.

Comment: Also, SANs aren't supported on Symbian OS 9.1 (and earlier) and Palm OS devices - http://www.digicert.com/subject-alternative-name-compatibility.htm

Comment: @jmac, the `*.mysubdomain.example.com` wildcard expression doesn't cover `mysubdomain.example.com` (the wildcard doesn't cover the dot). You'd need an extra SAN for this.

Comment: @Bruno you're right, but the DigiCert wildcard cert already includes the extra SAN for the base domain.  Excerpt from http://www.digicert.com/welcome/wildcard-plus.htm: DigiCert includes the base domain in every wildcard certificate as a subject alternative name, a little-used but well-supported capability of SSL certificates.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your certificate to be valid for both `*.mysubdomain.example.com` and `mysubdomain.example.com`, it needs to have a Subject Alternative Name entry for both.

The `*.mysubdomain.example.com` wildcard expression doesn't cover `mysubdomain.example.com`.

These rules are defined in [RFC 2818](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2818#section-3.1) and clarified in [RFC 6125](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6125#section-6.4.3):

> ```
>    If the wildcard character is the only character of the left-most
>    label in the presented identifier, the client SHOULD NOT compare
>    against anything but the left-most label of the reference
>    identifier (e.g., *.example.com would match foo.example.com but
>    not bar.foo.example.com or example.com).
> ```

In practice, that's indeed how most browsers react.

It's however quite likely that a CA issuing a wildcard certificate for `*.mysubdomain.example.com` will also add a SAN for `mysubdomain.example.com`. Check with your CA.

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple SSL certificates and add them all to the same endpoint by automating the process of installing the certificates on the machine and add HTTPS bindings to IIS.

IIS 8 (Windows Server 2012) supports SNI, which enables you to add a "hostheader" to the HTTPS binding.

I'm a Microsoft Technical Evangelist and I have posted a detailed explanation and a sample "plug & play" source-code at:
http://www.vic.ms/microsoft/windows-azure/multiples-ssl-certificates-on-windows-azure-cloud-services/